# how to extract part of text using regex on a data frame in pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame and one of the columns are like this:

```
df = index  dosage_duration
     0        5  years20mg 1X D
     1         2  days10mg 1X D
     2         2  days10mg 1X D
     3                 7  weeks
     4                2  months
     5                  3  days
     6             1  years5 MG
     7                 2  years
```

What I am trying to do is to extract the first part of the time and convert it to days.
So the result would look like this:

```
df = index  dosage_duration       new_dosage
     0        5  years20mg 1X D    5*365
     1         2  days10mg 1X D    2
     2         2  days10mg 1X D    2
     3                 7  weeks    7*7
     4                2  months    2*30
     5                  3  days    3
     6             1  years5 MG    1*365
     7                 2  years    2*365
```

As you see here, 5 years being converted to 5*365 to be as days.

I am able to get the first part lets to say `5` in the `first row`, `2` in the second row... but Im not sure how can I get the `years` `days` or `month` so I can change all the values to days scale.

Apparently, I need to be able to find the first number after the `space` but I don't know how can I do this part.

Comment: Dont post your data as images. Its hard to copy for others.

Comment: Instead of images, could you please provide some code to repro the issue? Please add the code that fails, too.

Comment: Sure, I will add data frame and the code I have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- split by space.
- the first element is your number.
- The second element indicates what kind of time it is? `day`,`week`, `month`,`year`. Just the first letter is enough to identify what to multiply.

```py
import pandas as pd

df  = pd.DataFrame({'dosage_duration':['5 years27abc','10 days92pqr', '5.5 weeks782364hgsdf', '3 months21647hadjh']})

mul = {
    'd':1,
    'w':7,
    'm':30,
    'y':365
}

df['new_dosage'] = df['dosage_duration'].apply(lambda x:x.split()).apply(lambda x:float(x[0])*mul[x[1][0]])
df
```

Output:

```
    dosage_duration     new_dosage
0   5 years27abc        1825
1   10 days92pqr        10
2   5.5 weeks782364hgsdf    35
3   3 months21647hadjh  90
```

Update:

- if you want them as string of expression.

```py
import pandas as pd

df  = pd.DataFrame({'t':['5 years27abc','10 days92pqr', '5 weeks782364hgsdf', '3 months21647hadjh']})

mul = {
    'd':'1',
    'w':'7',
    'm':'30',
    'y':'365'
}

df['total_time'] = df['t'].apply(lambda x:x.split()).apply(lambda x:x[0] + '*' + mul[x[1][0]])
df
```

Output:

```
          t             total_time
0   5 years27abc        5*365
1   10 days92pqr        10*1
2   5 weeks782364hgsdf  5*7
3   3 months21647hadjh  3*30
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Poojan. Actually Im getting this error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1.5'` and if I change to `float` it raises `KeyError: 't'`

Comment: You can change int to float in `lambda`

Comment: yea I did but it raises `KeyError: 't'`. do you have any idea of the reason?

Comment: My pandas data frame is sample data frame. Change column name in this according to your dataframe

Comment: @sariii Updated answer check.

Comment: Yea I have done that and my column name change to `dosage_duration`. let me inspect more but I didnt use ur column name

Comment: I think the reason is that I have null values in my data so that even if I fill null with 0 still it can not do the mapping? because it can not split it?

Comment: I get rid of any `NaN` values I had. now all the result showing `NaN`. Actually I dont get any error but the result is `nan`. do you have any idea what could be the reason?

Comment: Post your code in question. And without access to data its hard to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dosage_duration':['5 years20mg 1x D'
                                     ,'2 days10mg 1x D'
                                     ,'4 months20mg 1x D'
                                     ,'7 weeks'
                                     ,'2 months'
                                     ,'3 days'
                                     ,'1 days'
                                     ,'1 years5 MG'
                                     ,'2 years'
                                     ,'6 months'
                                     ,'1 years10 1x D'
                                     ,'10 months15']})

nmap={'years':365, 'months':30, 'weeks':7, 'days': 1}
strnmap = '|'.join(nmap.keys())

df_m = df.dosage_duration.str.extract(f'(?P<unit>\d+)\s?(?P<span>[{strnmap}]+)')
df['new_duration']= df_m['unit'].astype(int).mul(df_m['span'].map(nmap))

print(df)
```

Output:

```
      dosage_duration  new_duration
0    5 years20mg 1x D          1825
1     2 days10mg 1x D             2
2   4 months20mg 1x D           120
3             7 weeks            49
4            2 months            60
5              3 days             3
6              1 days             1
7         1 years5 MG           365
8             2 years           730
9            6 months           180
10     1 years10 1x D           365
11        10 months15           300
​
```